# Do DMLs in a stored procedure run in a single transaction?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

My MySQL 5.5 server has set `autocommit=1`.

My stored procedure has several DMLs but without explicit transaction management.

When I issue `call the_procedure()` from MySQL CLI (`autocommit` is still 1), do all the procedure's DMLs run in one transaction?

Or do they run in separate transactions, and causing implicit transaction commit after every DML (due to autocommit)?

Comment: Unless they've been willfully perverse, MySQL should probably behave the same as most other SQL databases - transactions and stored routines are orthogonal concepts - a single transaction can span multiple routines, a single routine can create and commit multiple transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They run in separate transactions if `autocommit=1`. Suppose you define

```
CREATE TABLE test ( id int PRIMARY KEY )//

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test_trans()
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (1);
  INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (2);
  ROLLBACK;
END//
```

If you run this procedure with `autocommit=0`, the `ROLLBACK` will undo the insertions. If you run it with `autocommit=1`, the `ROLLBACK` will do nothing. [Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f44de/2).

Another example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test_trans_2()
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (1);
  INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (1);
END//
```

If you run this procedure with `autocommit=0`, failure of the second insert will cause a `ROLLBACK` undoing the first insertion. If you run it with `autocommit=1`, the second insert will fail but the effects of the first insert will not be undone.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-stored-procedure/0596100892/re31.html) is surprising to me but:

> Although MySQL will automatically initiate a transaction on your
> behalf when you issue DML statements, you should issue an explicit
> START TRANSACTION statement in your program to mark the beginning of
> your transaction.
>
> It's possible that your stored program might be run within a server in
> which autocommit is set to TRUE, and by issuing an explicit START
> TRANSACTION statement you ensure that autocommit does not remain
> enabled during your transaction. START TRANSACTION also aids
> readability by clearly delineating the scope of your transactional
> code.

Comment: Thank you, does it suggest that DMLs in a procedure call run in one transaction?

Comment: O'reilly has renamed Safari Books Online to O'Reilly Learning, the link is now https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-stored-procedure/0596100892/re31.html

Answer (score 0):

Tests done in the following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/868de/4), shows that by not explicitly handle transactions are handled separately when the variable `autocommit` is 1 (TRUE).

Comment: Thanks for that, but my question is more about whether there is an implicit commit for each individual DMLs in a procedure, not a procedure call as a whole.